# php preg_replace h1.h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 with <p style="font-weight:bold;">

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have found in several places ways to replace one tag with another... so for instance, replacing `<h1> </h1>` with `<p> </p>`

However, I would like a preg_replace that can replace `<h[1-6]> </h[1-6]>` with `<p style="font-weight:bold;"> </p>`

Comment: I tried the following: preg_replace("~<(/)?h1>~", "<\\1p>", $str) ... which did not work perfect and would lead to having one for preg_replace for h1, one for h2, and so forth

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$html = preg_replace('/<h[1-6]>(.*?)<\/h[1-6]>/', '<p style="font-weight:bold">$1</p>', $html);
```

Be wary of using regex for HTML, though.

Comment: I actually made a little adjustment to the regex above: `$html = preg_replace('/<h[1-6](.*?)<\/h[1-6]>/si', '<p style="font-weight:bold"$1</p>', $html);` which will also take into consideration if the h1-6 tag has any attributes, inline-style, etc. I am not sure if it is the best way of doing, or if there is a better way, but it works.